# turn string into a UIColor swift

Tags: ios, string, swift, uicolor

I have buttons filled with Colors: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7qAh.png)

When user press on a color, a string is generated, i.e. 
`Yellow` or `Blue` or `Black` etc.

What i want is to load the string into a UIColor when i segue back:

```
garageNameLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor."THE STRING THAT WAS GENERATED"
```

I know that `UIColor.whiteColor()`, `blackColor()` is there.

code:

```
let theStringColor = Blue

garageNameLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.theStringColor
```

Thanks

Comment: "I know that UIColor.whiteColor(), blackColor() is there" There's no relationship between strings and code names. It would be up to you to build a table manually.

Comment: When you press a button, the app goes to other View?? or What's happens?

Comment: @oremag14jf  the app goes to another view and sets a label to the color you picked

Comment: I must be missing something - but why do you return a string description of the colour, and then go through further processing to turn that into an actual colour?  Why not set the return value to `UIColor.redColor()` instead of returning `Red` ?

Answer (score 5):

I solved the problem by making a dictionary

```
var colors : [String:UIColor] = ["White": UIColor.whiteColor(), "Black": 
UIColor.blackColor(), "Gray": UIColor.grayColor(),"Turquoise": 
UIColor.cyanColor(),"Red": 
UIColor.redColor(),"Yellow":UIColor.yellowColor(),"Blue": UIColor.blueColor(), 
"Green": UIColor.greenColor()]
```

and then loading the string into it i.e.:

```
let theStringColor = "Blue"

garageNameLabel.backgroundColor = colors[theStringColor]
```

Comment: Right, this is exactly what I meant by "build a table manually".

Answer (score 2):

In OBJC code like this works. i have not tested this code, only translated it from OBJC to swift.

```
private func setColorWithNameForLabel(label: UILabel, colorName: String) {
    let colorString = colorName + "Color" // if your colorName matches f.i. "black" --> blackColor
    let s = Selector(colorString)

    if let color = UIColor.performSelector(s).takeUnretainedValue() as? UIColor { // as of swift 2.0 you have to take the retained value
        label.textColor = color
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a parameter in the segue. In the new view, in the viewDidLoad () function, you can perform a check that change color depending on the value of the parameter.

```
if parameter == "blue" {
garageNameLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor ()
} Else if parameter == "green" {
garageNameLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor ()
}
```