# Unable to get value from String to UIColor

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uicolor

I am trying to change the backgroundColor of a few UIButtons based on a dictionary that I have saved the colors in String.

i.e

```
button1.backgroundColor = dic!.valueForKey("Button1Color") as? UIColor


  // in the dictionary:
    Button1Color = "UIColor.redColor()"
```

i get nil.
Why?

Comment: you are saving as string in dictionary and trying to get it as UIColor

Comment: in my plist there is no option for Type: UIColor

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35776473/turn-string-into-a-uicolor-swift?rq=1

Comment: You cannot save colors to plist and saving code as string won't work. If you want to save color information, you will have to convert its RGB value into a string or number.

Comment: Thanks @RasmusFriisKjeldsen that did solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could store the color as a string and use some library or code snippet (e.g. [here](https://github.com/yeahdongcn/UIColor-Hex-Swift)) to convert it to `UIColor` and back to string.

Alternatively, you could store the 4 `Float` numbers that make up a UIColor in a scheme similar to this:

```
let bg1: [String:CGFloat] = ["red": 1, "green": 0, "blue": 0, "alpha": 1]
```

and use the initializer `UIColor(red:green:blue:alpha)` to create a `UIColor` object.

NB: These are some ideas for **persisting** the data to disk. Obviously, in an **in-memory only** array you can put any object you like, including `UIColor`.